# Customize search of sugarcrm with a field of another table

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'd like to have a special search in sugarcrm : get all the accounts which have have events of a special type (for example, accounts which have customer visit)
Is it possible in sugarcrm ? (I use 6.2 CE)

Morerover, I'd like to force this special filter for user of a group
(a special type of user will only see account which have customer visit)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I found some interesting poste on the forum of sugarcrm + the howto on this web site.

When you follow that instruction :

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/04/19/howto-add-a-search-field-that-searches-another-module/

You can search with a textbox on your database

I had a problem when I wanted to use an enum field (select), the query was like cstm.nature_c LIKE  ''Op'%') and it didn't work

after that i found http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/issues-cross-module-search-enum-fields-77778/ and http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/search-through-fields-related-modules-57125/#post265614 which was the solution

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this myself. I finally came up with a solution that I've detailed here: [cross-module-search-implementation](https://suitecrm.com/forum/developer-help/3658-cross-module-search-implementation)